# oncreateview se ejecuta antes que el getextra

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragment

**Tengo la siguiente activity:**

```
 package com.joseamo.app;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class AlbumsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_albums);


    //toolbar
    androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar2);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    //recibe los intents y los pasa al fragment
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    long id = intent.getLongExtra("ID", 1);

    AlbumsFragment fragment = (AlbumsFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_album);
    fragment.setGrupo(id);


}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.toolbar2_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}
```

}

Esta activity contiene en su layout  un fragment y llama a su función setGrupo
**Este es el codigo del fragment**

```
package com.joseamo.app;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.ListFragment;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AlbumsFragment extends ListFragment {

    private long idgrupo;

    public AlbumsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }





    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Log.d("idvalor2",Long.valueOf(idgrupo)+"");

        String [] albumes = new String[GruposData.Gruposlist[(int)idgrupo].datos.size()];


        for(int i = 0; i<GruposData.Gruposlist[(int)idgrupo].datos.size(); i++){

            albumes[i]=GruposData.Gruposlist[(int)idgrupo].datos.get(i).album;

        }


        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(inflater.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,albumes);
        setListAdapter(adapter);




        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_albums, container, false);
    }

    public void setGrupo (long id)
    {
        idgrupo=id;
        Log.d("idvalor",Long.valueOf(idgrupo)+"");


    }



}
```

El problema viene porque necesito que se ejecute el método SetGrupo  antes que el onCreateView para que el valor de "idgrupo" sea el que le he marcado desde la actividad, y no 0 que es el valor que se pone por defecto

llevo varias horas debugeando y mediante Logcat he verificado que los metodos funcionan, el problema esque el onCreateView se ejecuta antes de poder setearle un valor a "idgrupo"

Este es el log del logcat:

2021-05-09 03:23:09.632 15537-15537/com.joseamo.app D/idvalor2: 0
2021-05-09 03:23:09.646 15537-15537/com.joseamo.app D/idvalor: 1

Answer (score 2):

De la forma como tratas de llamar el mètodo `setGrupo()` este sera llamado siempre despuès de `onCreateView()` del `Fragment`:

```
  AlbumsFragment fragment = (AlbumsFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_album);
    fragment.setGrupo(id);
```

La forma correcta es que tengas un `FrameLayout` donde realizarìas la transacciòn del Fragment:

de esta forma podrìas enviar el valor al inicializar el `Fragment` :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_albums);


    //toolbar
    androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar2);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    //recibe los intents y los pasa al fragment
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    long id = intent.getLongExtra("ID", 1);

    //AlbumsFragment fragment = (AlbumsFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_album);
    //fragment.setGrupo(id);

    //Realiza transaccion de Fragment y envia valores...
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putExtra("idvalor", id );
    AlbumsFragment fragment = new AlbumsFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    transaction.replace(R.id.mycontainer, fragment);
    transaction.commit();



}
```

Dentro del `Fragment` en el mètodo `onCreateView()` puedes obtener el valor que deseas:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
    if (extras != null) {
        long id = extras.getLong("idvalor");
    }
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```